# du -ah gives different result on same folder accessible through smb (Samba)

Tags: 18.04, mount, samba, disk-usage

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server. When I'm running `du -ah` in directories, I get different values whether I am ssh-ed on it or if I mounted it.

When I ssh-ed on the machine:

```
myusername@server:/share/biblio$ du -ah
265M    ./foo1.csv
190M    ./foo2.csv
455M    .
```

When I mounted it on my machine using the graphic interface (the protocol used is `Samba`):

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=SERVERNAME,share=biblio$ du -ah
930M    ./foo1.csv
739M    ./foo2.csv
1,7G    .
```

I have seen in the man page of `du` that there is a `BLOCK_SIZE`, `DU_BLOCK_SIZE` or `BLOCKSIZE` variable that can be set. But none of them were.
I also checked if there were any aliases, but there are none.

Why is there a factor ~3.5 in the size between the 2 commands?